# Solspace Calendar Locations

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I could not find it in the docs and hope someone that has used it before can answer it.

How does Solspace Calendar handle location data.  I did not see a way to add a location like Venti 2 has.  Right now I am using VZ Address in conjunction with Calendar. Is that the best way to go about achieving an address for an event with Solspace Calendar?

Comment: Another option to VZ Address is to use Easy Address Field (https://github.com/studioespresso/craft3-easyaddressfield). The author seems to be keeping the plugin current, and responded almost immediately to a documentation request I made. Basically, you just add it as a custom field to your event entry. But there's nothing built in to Solspace calendar that allows for geolocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently isn't any built in Location field for Calendar. We made add something like that in the future, but for now you can definitely use other third party field types such as [VZ Address](https://github.com/elivz/VzAddress-Craft) to handle this. :)